# Iconvertible Issue with dapper C#

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I'm trying to get a value from the database using Dapper but when I execute the query<> instruction I receive an "object must implement Iconvertible" exception.  What I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

The error occurred when I call the Decrypt method and it call the ExceuteQuery Function.

***Code***

**Program**

```
ServiceSettingsEntity appSetting = MainRepository.GetConfigSettings(appSettingKey.ToString(), companyCode);
    
                   
if (appSetting.IsEncrypted)
    appSetting.Value = MainRepository.Decrypt(appSetting.Value);
    return appSetting.Value.Trim();
```

**Decrypt Funtion**

```
public static string Decrypt(string encryptedData)
{

    CommandSettings commandSettings = new CommandSettings
    {
        CommandText = @"[Utility].[DecryptData]",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        Parameters = new
                        {
                          @DataToDecrypt = encryptedData
                        }};
        
    return new MsSqlProviderBase(EdxDbConnectionString, 
                 commandSettings).ExecuteQuery<string>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**ExecuteQuery function used to encapsulate the dapper Query<> function**

```
public List<T> ExecuteQuery<T>()
{
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = DbConnection)
    {
        List<T> qResult = dbConnection.Query<T>(CommandSettings.CommandText, 
                             CommandSettings.Parameters,                     
                             commandTimeout: CommandSettings.CommandTimeout,
                             commandType: 
                                CommandSettings.CommandType).ToList();
                
return qResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that `Utility.DecryptData` returns a `varchar`? If it's `varbinary`, the underlying .NET type (depending on the `IDbConnection` provider running beneath Dapper) will probably be `byte[]`.

Comment: Hi! Yes it is a varbinary but I'm convertng it to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on expanded info in comments.) Most `IDbConnection` implementations will (correctly) "translate" SQL `varbinary` to C# `byte[]`. `byte[]` and `string` are not immediately convertible, because [natural language text is complex](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx).

You will need to translate your `string` to a `byte[]` and vice-versa using an encoding before the underlying stored procedure is usable.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding). The upshot: once you select an encoding, you'll use the `GetBytes(string)` and `GetString(byte[])` methods to en/decode the text going into and coming out of the stored procedure.